# Sum of arithmetico-geometric series

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

Could use help trying to find the following sum of series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N r^n\sqrt{a + nd}  $$

I have no clue where to begin on this one.

Ideally would like solution for all $ r $ but if it helps to assume $ r < 1 $ then we can start with assuming that.

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed form solution?

Comment: I don't, but if there isn't, how to prove there isn't?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\sqrt{a+ndr^n}$ or $r^n\cdot\sqrt{a+nd}$?

Comment: Proving there isn't a closed form for a sum is nigh impossible. When I say there isn't I mean that nobody has come up with one so far.

Comment: @BenLongo The second one $ r^n \sqrt{a + nd} $

Comment: WWRD What would Ramanujan do?

Comment: @amcalde Didn't they do that for the quintic equation =D ?

Comment: Note that wolframalpha knows a closed form when $a=0$, involving the Lerch transcendent and the polylogarithm.

Comment: @Slade do those really count as closed form? I thought the Lerch and polylog were just abbreviations for values of certain infinite series. What are the actual closed form representations of those values?

Comment: @seanmedford I said "nigh"

Comment: @seanmedford I mean, if you want a specific answer, you should ask a specific question.  Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}/2^n$ can be written in terms of the polylogarithm only, you could possibly use existing results about expressing the polylogarithm in terms of elementary functions to arrive at a negative answer to the question of existence of a "closed form".  But again, this would require asking a question that is much less vague.

Comment: Wolfram is able to give a closed form of the indefinite integral (involving the error function).

Comment: When $r>1$, substitute $n'=N-n+1$, and $S(N;r,a,d)=r^{N+1}S(N,1/r,a+(N+1)d,-d)$.

Comment: (1) What Ramanujan would do baffled even Hardy and Littlewood.(2) A "closed form" without qualifications, is not a precise term. The exponential function $e^x$ for complex $x$ is defined (usually) by a power series,for example.

Comment: OK then. I would be open to an answer to the partial summation using the Lerch Tr. and the Polylog. The below answer does not answer the original question of an expression for the partial summation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't going to be a 'nice' closed form, and as amcalde mentions, proving that seems hard. For the infinite series, we can write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\sqrt{a+nd}=\sqrt{d}\Phi\left(r,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{a}{d}\right)-\sqrt{a},$$ where $\Phi$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Comment: Any insights towards an expression for the partial summation?